# How to change the way xml schema is generated by xsd?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, xsd

I'm very new to generating xsd schema from classes using visual studio xsd.exe tool and I have a sample scenarios here, reduced for simplicity's sake.

Here is a sample of my classes

```
public class quality
{
    ....
    public List<Application> Applications { get; set; }
}

public class Application
{
    ...
    public int LOC { get; set; }
    public Int32 DebtInDollars { get; set; }
    public Int32 DebtDensity { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

The schema that xsd generated is "flat" so to speak.. like so

```
<xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <xs:complexType name="quality">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Applications" type="ArrayOfApplication" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="ArrayOfApplication">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Application" nillable="true" type="Application" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:element name="Application" nillable="true" type="Application" />
  <xs:complexType name="Application">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="LOC" type="xs:int" />
      <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="DebtInDollars" type="xs:int" />
      <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="DebtDensity" type="xs:int" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

What I want to generate is more of a hierarchical structure as I have seen in some other schema like below, it makes more sense to me....

```
       <xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <xs:complexType name="quality">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="Applications">
             <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                  <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Application">
                        <xs:complexType>
                             <xs:sequence>
                                      <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="LOC" type="xs:int" />
                                      <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="DebtInDollars" type="xs:int" />
                                      <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="DebtDensity" type="xs:int" />
                            </xs:sequence>
                        </xs:complexType>
                  </xs:element>
                </xs:sequence>
              </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Is there anyway to achieve that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if you can control the XSD generation by decorating it with attributes as explained in the following MSDN article. I know it is for serialization, but the generated schema in XSD defines the XML format used by System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer(v=vs.110).aspx

I did not try it, but might be worth a try.

Comment: Thanks George. I'll play around with the annotations and see how it works. Greatly appreciate it.